# JavaScript Programação

Tags: javascript

Estou com uma dúvida em javascript,

código:

```
function abrirNav(){
    if (document.getElementById("style-switcher").style.width="0px"{
    document.getElementById("style-switcher").style.width="200px";
}
```

preciso que quando o `width` do `style-switcher`:

- estiver `0`, mude para `200px`,
- estiver em `200px` mude para `0`.

Se alguem puder me ajudar ficarei grato.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o [offsetWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth) para isso, exemplo:

```js
function changeSize(){
  const element = document.getElementById('myDiv');
  
  if(element.offsetWidth === 0){
    element.style.width = '200px';
  } else {
    element.style.width = '0px';
  }
}
```

```css
#myDiv{
  width: 0px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
  
  transition: width 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>

<br />
<button onclick="changeSize()">Click me!</button>
```

A ideia é que você mantenha um referimento ao elemento salvado em uma variável, e que através da mesma você possa obter o `width` e outras propriedades do seu elemento e até mesmo altera-las.